# How to evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z) dz}{(z-z_1)^{m_1}(z-z_2)^{m_2}}$ and the other related contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Respected All.

I was studying residue theory where I came accross the following problem

"If $f$ be analytic in the simply connected domain $D$ and $z_1, z_2$ are two distinct complex point lying in the interior to the simple closed contour $C$ having positive orientation (that also lies in $D$), then show that 
$$\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z) dz}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}."$$

I managed the solution. After that it attacked in my mind, what about

(i) if there are $n$ points say $z_1, \cdots, z_n$ are inside $C$? What closed form formula we shall receive for $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z) dz}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots (z-z_n)}$?

(ii) And what about $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z) dz}{(z-z_1)^{m_1}(z-z_2)^{m_2}}$ where $m_1, m_2$ are any positive integers ?

In both the ways I stuck. Can anyone help me out of this please ? Like would be there any specific technique to tackle this type of problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ does not vanish in $z_1,\ldots, z_n$, otherwise you just factor out the common zeros.

$h(z)=f(z)(z-z_1)^{-1}\cdots(z-z_n)^{-1}$ has simple poles (at most) in $z_1,\ldots, z_n$. Therefore
$$\mathrm{Res}(h,z_j)=\lim_{z\to z_j}(z-z_j)h(z)=f(z_j)\prod_{k\neq j}(z_j-z_k)^{-1}$$
So your first integral is equal to the sum over $j$ of such expressions.

$g(z)=f(z)(z-z_1)^{-a}(z-z_2)^{-b}$ has poles of order $a$ and $b$. Hence
$$\mathrm{Res}(h,z_1)=\dfrac{1}{(a-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_1}\dfrac{d^{a-1}}{dz^{a-1}}((z-z_1)^ah(z))=\dfrac{1}{(a-1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}\binom{a-1}{m}(-1)^{m}\dfrac{(b-1+m)!}{(b-1)!}f^{(a-1-m)}(z_1)(z_1-z_2)^{-b-m}$$
So your second integral is
$$\dfrac{1}{(a-1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}\binom{a-1}{m}(-1)^{m}\dfrac{(b-1+m)!}{(b-1)!}f^{(a-1-m)}(z_1)(z_1-z_2)^{-b-m}+\dfrac{1}{(b-1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{b-1}\binom{b-1}{m}(-1)^{m}\dfrac{(a-1+m)!}{(a-1)!}f^{(b-1-m)}(z_2)(z_2-z_1)^{-a-m}$$